# Old certificate shows for windows server in remote desktop connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, certificate, ssl-certificate

I had remote access from a windows computer to a windows server. The server's certificate recently expired and we replaced it to a new one. We also removed the old certificate from the server. Afterwards we verified that the new certificate had been activated.

The thing is that in computers that had had access via RDC to the server, we still get the warning for the old certificate along with its data. When opening RDC in other computers, we don't get the warning though.

My best guess is that the data for the old certificate are stored in my computer (and that of other colleagues). Is that a meaningful assumption. Do I have to worry about it? How can I get rid of this warning and have the new certificate display?

I did restart the computer, in case it matters. The warning for the old certificate persists.

Comment: Did you remove the expired certiifcate from every machine's certificate store?

Comment: @Ramhound From the computers that had remote access, you mean? No, I did not. My assumption was that the old certificate is stored somewhere, but I did not know if that is the case and where to search.

Comment: I just told you.  The certificate store. There is lots of documentation, that exists, that explains how to view the user's certificate store on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue with an RDG server.

In IIS, make sure 443 is bound to the new cert and not the old one.  If you deleted the old cert, it may no longer be bound to a cert.